# How to get HTML5 validation message with selenium?

Tags: java, html, selenium, validation

Please see [this](http://exam.doubleoctopus.com/exam.html#) website.

After click log in i have this User credentials form and after try to login with missing `Email Address` or `Password` i got this message:

[image]

So i try to find this element by print all the page `HTML` (`driver.getPageSource()`) but this text is missing.

Any idea how to verify that i have this error message?

Comment: I think that is specific to Chrome and is not actually HTML in/on the page. I've seen questions like this before and I've tried to find it myself but was unable to. If you create a simple page and add an INPUT that contains the `required` attribute, if you try to submit the form while it's empty, you will get this message. You can see in the simple case that there is no HTML generated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The validation messages are not the part of your DOM. They are generated because your input fileds have `required` attribute. If you see the HTML of your fields -

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required="">
```

You can see it has required attribute turned on. Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_required.asp) out. You can verify that your fields have this required attribute or not, like this-

```
WebElement inputElement = driver.findElement(By.name("uname"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
boolean isRequired = (Boolean) js.executeScript("return arguments[0].required;",inputElement)
if(isRequired )
{
   //element is required and validation error will popup if the field is empty.
}
```

There is no need to care about whether the message appears or not because that will handled by the browser.

Answer (score 8):

Attribute `validationMessage` will return the message, that will be showing if validation fails:

```
WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.name("uname"));    
String validationMessage = username.getAttribute("validationMessage");
```

If element has `required` attribute, browser will show the message after submitting the form:

```
boolean required = Boolean.parseBoolean(username.getAttribute("required"));
```

You can check whether entered value is valid:

```
boolean valid = (Boolean)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].validity.valid;", username);
```

---

**Not**: message text and validation is customizable. If you want to test customized 
validation and message.

Here test code for custom validation(Java, TestNG):

```
Assert.assertTrue(Boolean.parseBoolean(username.getAttribute("required")), "Username is required and message should be showin");
Assert.assertEquals(username.getAttribute("validationMessage"), "My custom message", "Message text control");

username.sendKeys("@vasya ");
Assert.assertTrue((Boolean)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].validity.valid;", username), "Username has special characters");
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this by calling the element's reportValidity() method within the Selenium test.  In C# we can use driver.executeScript().  For Java I'm sure it's something similar.  If you don't execute the script then you have to look for the generic message, which is "Please fill out this field".  Here's the code sample:

```
    wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions
        .ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("input#NewPassword.form-control")));
    IWebElement input = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input#NewPassword.form-control"));
    input.SendKeys(string.Empty);
    IWebElement form = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("form"));        
    form.Submit();
    *driver.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('NewPassword').reportValidity();");*
    Assert.AreEqual("New password required", input.GetAttribute("validationMessage"));
```