# How do you confirm HTML5 validation messages using Protractor?

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing

I'm setting up a Protractor demo for work. I'm trying to get it to read HTML5 error validation messages (such as invalid email). It was quite simple using Cypress. How can I do this using Protractor?

In cypress, it was a simple

```
expect($email.get(0).validationMessage)
.to.equal('Please include an \'@\' in the email address. \'thisismyemail\' is missing an \'@\'.');
```

Comment: Find the selector of the element that displays the error message and then call `.getText()` on it. `emailMsg = element(by.css(<email-msg-selector>)`. Then `expect(emailMsg.getText()).toEqual('Please include an \'@\' in the email address. \'thisismyemail\' is missing an \'@\'.');`

Comment: there's nothing in the css. the error message is a default HTML5 error message build into browsers.

Comment: Can you provide the html so we can help provide a locator. Typically the locator is the a validation class

Comment: Something like this in most browsers will give error messages for invalid emails (such as having no @ sign). I was wanting to test for when these popped up when erroneous entries were made my tests with protractor.


<html>

<body>

<form method="get">

<input type="email" name="email"><button type="submit" formmethod="post">send</button>

</form>

</body>

</html>

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52029267/how-to-get-html5-validation-message-with-selenium/52030901), [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178122/how-to-check-if-an-html5-validation-was-triggered-using-selenium) are two questions which may be off use to use with this.